# How to check whether child window exists if parent window redirects to some other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

On clicking the button a child window is opened:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="myWindow = window.open('http://www.example.com/index', '', 'toolbars=0,resizable,scrollbars')">Start</button>
```

The parent window will redirect to another page on button click.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    parent.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/popup';
});
```

If I did not redirect the parent window, I am able to check whether the child window exist from the parent window like this:

```
if(!myWindow.closed){
    alert('Yup, still there.');}
```

Since the parent window is redirecting I am not able to check whether `myWindow` is closed or not.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible by javascript on an easy way. This is because of the security. Imagine what a mess it whould be if a website could access all the tabs you have opened. So Javascript is limited to the DOM of the page it's delivered with.

So what you can do is using websockets. There is a rails implementation of websockets called `websocket-rails`. This allows you to communicate with your clients asynchron. So that whould enable you to implement a method that verifies that a vertan page is opened by a client.

Websockets arent that easy to understand in the beginning but they are definitfily worth a read!

Comment: Ohh I see. Then I will try websockets. Thanks for the info!